# Back button is not visible in iOS 7

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7

I have some weird trouble about iOS 7. I have an `UINavigationBar` in my app and it works perfect for iOS 6;

-- **IOS 6** --

[image]

However, when i try to run it on iOS 7, my back button disappeared. It's there, still working and clickable but not visible;

-- **IOS 7** --

[image]

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this on the dev forums.  iOS 7 is still under NDA, so just about everybody here will be hesitant to answer

Comment: Can you show us your iOS 6 code? Maybe we can help you without violating the iOS 7 NDA.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824887/ios-7-custom-back-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `BackButtonBackgroundImage` via `UIAppearance` currently has some odd behavior in iOS 7. This is probably related to the updated design, which replaces the rect-style button with a backIndicatorImage (an arrow).

This leaves 3 options for customizing the back button's appearance:

1. Change the color of the backIndicatorImage by setting the `tintColor` property on `UINavigationBar` (or one of its superclasses).
2. Set the new `backIndicatorImage` property on `UINavigationBar` to a custom image. (don't forget to set the `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` as well or it won't work)
3. Create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` and manually assign it as `UINavigationItem`'s `leftBarButtonItem`. (See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18825143/2245647) mentioned above by [Mashhadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339171/mashhadi))

Answer (score 2):

By the way, if you have to keep support ios 6 version like me, use that;

```
   if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
        {
            // My iOS 6 back button background 
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:39.0f/255.0f green:184.0f/255.0f blue:199.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        }
        else
        {
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Wes Dearborn's answer and implemented a nice way of supporting both iOS5+'s back button and iOS7's backIndicatorImage:

[Back button strangely disappearing in UINavigationController but keeps working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236410/back-button-strangely-disappearing-in-uinavigationcontroller-but-keeps-working/19238312#19238312)